# How to replace a specific but changing series of characters in an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, replace, char

I am working on 2 different programs, but have the same problem for both. I have a `char` array (that doesn't hold meaningful text) that I use for drawing things on the screen. The first one is for a race line that shows progress, and the other one for the map of an area that can be modified.
What I want to do is overwrite a *section* of the array, not the entire array, without changing the array's size. For example, if `array1` looks like `|..........|` and I wanted to add a fallen tree at position 3 and a rock at position 10 it would change to `|..-->>>..@|`. What I meant in my title for 'specific' is that the amount of characters to be replaced is given by me or determined during execution, instead of calling a function that automatically knows when to stop.
I thought of doing it with a `for` loop, like:

```
char tree[5] = "-->>>";
char map[12] = "|..........|";
int offset = 3; //position from which to start replacing characters
object_size = sizeof(tree) / sizeof(char); //to get the length of the object to be added
for (int i = 0; i < object_size; i++) {
    map[offset + i] = tree[i];
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do it? I'm sure there must already be a function that does it, but most of what I find is in other languages. The idea is to then be able to use a 2-dimensional array to store the map and modify bigger areas.

Comment: If your `map` string indeed is a regular C string, you can use a straight `strncpy`. This will copy the string in position, without the terminating zero. (Note that `../sizeof(char)` is redundant, as `sizeof(char) == 1` per the C specifications.)

Comment: `char tree[5] = "-->>>";` oups, where is the place for the terminating null??? It should be `char tree[6] = "-->>>";` or `char tree[] = "-->>>";` to let the compiler count for you.

Comment: Can code _assume_ inputs like `array1, tree,map, offset` are all well behaved together, or should code be resilient to troublesome cases like `offset > strlen(map)`?  Without a stated model of error handling - if any, "a cleaner way to do it" is moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have correctly understood, you do not want to copy the terminating null. The standard library function to use is `void *memcpy(void *dest, void *src, size_t size)` that copies exactly `size` bytes from `src` to `dest`.

But **you** have to ensure that there is enough room at dest to accept the size bytes

Comment: Detail: With OP's `char tree[5] = "-->>>";`, there is no null character to copy or not - nor is one truly needed here.  Agree `memcpy(map +offset, tree, sizeof tree)` should meet OP's goal - which seems to not be concerned with error checking.

Comment: Thanks. I initialized the arrays incorrectly. Is there any difference between a character array with no '\0' at the end (because it was initialized like `array[] = {'-', '-', '>', '>', '>'}` and a character array initialized with a string, besides the terminating NULL character at the end?
I guess if I store it like a string I can output the lines of the map using printf() instead of a `for` loop, but other than that they have the same qualities and are stored the same, right?

Comment: @FranciscoAyrolo: I'm unsure I have met your point. A C string is an array of characters terminated with a null character. And all C string functions knows about that. For me, the the only difference is that you cannot use a character array not terminated by a null as a C string, for example in `printf`, or any `strxx` function. Said differently any C string is a character array, but not all character arrays are C strings

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I was unsure of whether I should store the maps and objects as strings or arrays, but now I see the clear advantage.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/string_h.htm

And for you,

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)

char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
```

They can make your code cleaner, but i think that deep inside, they do what you're doing manually.